# Is it possible for Orfeo toolbox to do auto object identification on a 3band RGB raster image?

Tags: qgis, raster, remote-sensing, orfeo-toolbox, rgb

My intention of using Orfeo Toolbox is to find all the open air basketball courts on a raster image with 3 bands RGB.

Does OTB require a multi spectral band image or is 3 band image good enough to perform auto object identification.

Comment: Edited. Please pardon my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there is no specific requirement in Orfeo Toolbox about the input image format and you'll be able to process any type of multi-spectral image from 3 band RGB raster to hyperspectral images with hundreds bands.